# How to add fingerprint to my app independently to the fingerprints in the system?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to develop an Android app that uses a fingerprint as authentication.

I found many tutorials use the fingerprints which are stored in the system where fingerprint screen lock must be enabled also.

But this doesn't make sense to lock your app while the phone is locked!
Is there any independent way to implement fingerprint as authentication

Comment: hmmm.... ' fingerprint screen lock must be enabled' I think it means that the phone must have fingerprint set. User can remove their fingerprint lock anytime they want.

Comment: I tried to remove screen lock on the eliminator then it removes all fingerprints

Comment: _"fingerprint screen lock must be enabled also"_ A PIN code would also work. IIRC, the cryptographic keys that you associate with fingerprint authentications are encrypted with a Key Encryption Key, which in turn is derived from some secret (e.g. the user's PIN). _"this doesn't make sense to lock your app while the phone is locked"_ Then perhaps you don't need fingerprint authentication in your app. However, if the fingerprint authentication is used for something like confirming a purchase, then it would not be desireable to bypass the per-purchase control just because the devce is unlocked.